# Modelling sorting of a collection in a RESTful way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm have a simple rails app which uses mongoid. I have a parent document embedding some child documents via embeds_many/embedded_in. The user should be able to modify the ordering of the embedded documents (move up, move down, move top, ...). I wonder how to design that in a RESTful way using existing Rails functionality if possible. I'm of course able to create a controller action which gets the id of the children and moves it. But I thinks that's not the idea of REST. From a REST point of view it should be an update of the container holding the elements. But I have no idea how to implement/design that!? Any hint or starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically want to use PUT to update an existing resource. In this case, you're updating the ordinal of a member of a collection, so you would just do an update. The problem is that you have to update the ordinals of every member in the collection to avoid collisions and ensure that the order is unambiguous. So you want to update the collection entirely…

```
# routes.rb
resources :items do
  put '/sort' => 'items#sort', :on => :collection
end

# items_controller.rb
def sort
  # update your ordinals however you need
end
```

You *can* update each member for actions like "move to top", but it tends to be easier in most cases for the interface to specify the order of all elements for each update request. In other words, the front-end/api user specifies all element ids in the order they should be as parameters to `PUT /items/sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Often you have requirements that don't map perfectly into the pre-defined verbs of REST, but that's okay so long as you observe the spirit of REST.

For instance, an action that adjusts the position of an existing item is a PUT request with a custom verb. You could define a single verb `position` or multiple verbs like `up` and `down` depending on how you prefer to do it. In this case, `position` could be any of `top`, `bottom`, `up`, or `down` if you want to implement those.

Adding a custom route is pretty straightforward:

```
resources :items, :member => { :position => :put }
```

This will create a new verb `position` and route it to `ItemsController#position` accordingly.